# Как скопировать/сохранить docker volume на windows

Tags: windows, docker

Создан `volume`:
`docker volume create --name postgresql -d local`

Где он хранится? Как его можно скопировать/сохранить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы используете `WSL 2` для `Docker Desktop`, то ваш `volume` будет храниться в:

```
\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes\postgresql\
```

Если в качестве виртуальной машины используется, что-то другое `Hyper-V`, `VirtualBox` и т.д., то ваш `volume` можно будет найти по обычному пути (внутри этой машины):

```
/var/lib/docker/volumes/postgresql/
```